# Connect to a SQL Server database with Outlook

Tags: sql, sql-server, vba, outlook

I want to connect to a MS SQL Server database using an Outlook macro. But I don't know if the code is wrong or I need to add a library/driver or what happens here but it doesn't work.

```
Private Sub Application_Startup()
On Error GoTo ExitHere
    'adodb connection to other database
    stg_cn.Open "Provider = SQLOLEDB;" & _
                        "Data Source = 192.168.100.100;" & _
                        "Initial Catalog = hugeDB;" & _
                        "Integrated Security=SSPI;" & _
                        "User ID = oneuser;" & _
                        "Password = onepassword;"

    sQuery = "SELECT * FROM documents where location = 'IE'"

    'set reference to query
    Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
        cmd.ActiveConnection = stg_cn
        cmd.CommandType = adCmdText
        cmd.CommandText = sQuery
    Set rs = cmd.Execute
    Do While Not rs.EOF
        For i = 0 To rs.Fields.count - 1
            MsgBox (i + 1)
        Next
        rs.MoveNext
    Loop
ExitHere:
    If Not stg_cn Is Nothing Then stg_cn.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    Set stg_cn = Nothing
    Exit Sub

End Sub
```

Comment: the  error/issue is? You're not giving us much to go on.

Comment: You've said an Outlook macro, but the code starts with `Workbook_Open` which is Excel.  Should the procedure be called `Application_Startup` if it's in Outlook?

Comment: I've changed that but it doesn't work either... 
Could it be because the way I connect to the database should be different?

Answer (score 8):

On eye-test I am not able to figure out whats wrong, I think it has to do something with the way you are doing the ADO operations.

But I am just putting up the last macro I wrote to connect to SQL-Server from Macro. Hope it helps.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    '**************************************Initialize Variables**************************************
    sServer = "<SQL SERVER Server>"
    sDBName = "<SQL SERVER DB>"

    '**************************************Open Connection**************************************
    'adodb connection to other database
    stg_cn.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=" & sServer & _
                  ";Initial Catalog=" & sDBName & _
                  ";Integrated Security=SSPI;"

    sQuery = "SELECT * " & _
             "FROM Table "

    'set reference to query
    Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
        cmd.ActiveConnection = stg_cn
        cmd.CommandType = adCmdText
        cmd.CommandText = sQuery
    Set rs = cmd.Execute
    Do While Not rs.EOF
        For i = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1
            <PERFORM OPERATIONS>
        Next
        rs.MoveNext
    Loop

ExitHere:
    If Not stg_cn Is Nothing Then stg_cn.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    Set stg_cn = Nothing
    Exit Sub

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

The connection string @CodePhobia has provided should work for you.

The below just includes User ID and Password functionality, as your original question showed trying to connect using this.

```
Dim rsConn as ADODB.Connection
Set rsConn = New ADODB.Connection
With rsConn
    .ConnectionString = "Provider = sqloledb;" & _
                        "Data Source = myServerName;" & _
                        "Initial Catalog = myCatalog;" & _
                        "Integrated Security=SSPI;" & _
                        "User ID = myUserID;" & _
                        "Password = myPassword;"
    .Open
End With
```

You can use [this website](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/) to find connection strings in the future. It should cover all possible connections you wish to establish.

Comment: ...The database cannot be reached... I'm pretty sure the IP, table, username and password are correct. <code> Conn.connectionString = "Provider = sqloledb;" & _ "Data Source = hugeDB;" & _ "Integrated Security=SSPI;" & _ "User ID = hdbmread;" & _ "Password = hdbmreadonly;" Conn.Open Set Rst.ActiveConnection = Conn Rst.Open "select COUNT(*) from Nav n" & _ "group by n.Nav_Date" rs.Close Set rs = Nothing CN.Close Set CN = Nothing End Sub <code>

Comment: Have you included `"Initial Catalog = myCatalog;" & _` in your connection string? This is the catalog within the database you want to connect to.

Comment: Conn.connectionString = "Provider = sqloledb;" & _
                        "Data Source = 192.168.100.100;" & _
                        "Initial Catalog=" & hugeDB & _
                        "Integrated Security=SSPI;" & _
                        "User ID = hdbmread;" & _
                        "Password = hdbmreadread;"
 Still the same issue. It cannot connect from Outlook, but I can do it through Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio, therefore is not a problem with permissions...
I'm blocked here and it should be easy.

Comment: The `Data Source` should be the server name; is your server name an IP address?

Comment: In my macro I have the server name. Here I've added the IP but just because I didn't want to use the same internal names we use in the company. But yes, I'm using the server name.

Comment: Got you. Fair enough, well providing all of the details are correct, that should connect you to the server. Without seeing the actual details and knowing the server you're trying to connect to, I'm afraid there's not much else I can advise.